# Creating variable for unique ID on grouped data condition

Tags: r

Good Day Everyone!

I've come across a small challenge to create a new variable based on grouped data for each unique ID.

This is my dataset:

```
ID = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4")
CAL_YEAR = c("2010", "2011", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2013")
T_F = c("T", "F", "F", "T", "F", "F", "T")

DF_1 = data.frame(ID, CAL_YEAR, T_F)
```

This should be my final output:

```
ID = c("1", "1", "2", "2", "2", "3", "4")
CAL_YEAR = c("2010", "2011", "2010", "2011", "2011", "2012", "2013")
T_F = c("T", "F", "F", "T", "F", "F", "T")
VAR_TF = c("T", "F", "F", "T + F", "T + F", "F", "T")

DF_2 = data.frame(ID, CAL_YEAR, T_F, VAR_TF)
```

I'm looking for an elegant method to:

For each unique ID, by CAL_YEAR: IF T_F = "T" or "F" only, THEN VAR_TF = "T" or "F"

My challenge is on unique ID "2", CAL_YEAR "2011", where T_F contains "T" & "F". For this case, I would like VAR_TF to = "T + F" for each "T" & "F".

Comment: If the lengths are same, then try `ave(T_F, ID, CAL_YEAR, FUN = function(x) if(length(unique(x)) > 1) "T+F" else x)`

Comment: Thanks for your comment, I just corrected the code blocks for lengths of the variables and to incorporate them into a data.frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can use `ave` by checking the length of unique elements in 'T_F' grouped by 'ID', 'CAL_YEAR" and if it is greater than 1, then return "T + F" or else the original vector

```
DF_1$VAR_TF <- with(DF_1, ave(as.character(T_F), ID, CAL_YEAR,
        FUN = function(x) if(length(unique(x)) > 1) "T + F" else x))

identical(DF_1$VAR_TF, as.character(DF_2$VAR_TF))
#[1] TRUE
```

---

Or using `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)
DF_1 %>%
   group_by(ID, CAL_YEAR) %>%
   mutate(VAR_TF = if(n_distinct(T_F) > 1) "T + F" else as.character(T_F))
```

Comment: This was interesting to see the use of the 'ave' function. Now, this method works on the assumption of the variable T_F containing only two unique values, T & F, and 3 combinations of T, F & T+F. How would I adapt this method, to include a third unique value, C and a combination of T + F and T + F + C, given similar styled DF_1

Comment: @MPM It is based on the example you provided

Comment: Apologies, my previous comment got cut short, to follow: How would I adapt this method, to include a third unique value, C and a combination of T + F and T + F + C, given similar styled DF_1